# I can't run scripts from R in QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, sf, geopackage

**Try to run one of the scripts from R in QGIS and show me the next message.**

- Versión de QGIS: 3.28.3-Firenze
- Revisión del código de QGIS: c12bcb2f76c
- Versión de Qt: 5.15.3
- Python version: 3.9.5
- Versión de GDAL: 3.6.2
- Versión de GEOS: 3.11.1-CAPI-1.17.1
- Versión de PROJ: Rel. 9.1.1, December 1st, 2022
- PDAL version: 2.4.3 (git-version: f8d673)
- R versión: QGIS R Provider version 3.0.0, R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt) -- "Innocent and Trusting"

El algoritmo comenzó en: 2023-02-15T15:34:28
Algoritmo '1. Histogram 1' comenzando…

Parámetros de entrada:

```
{ 'Layer' : 'C:/Users/pedro/Desktop/R_and_Qgis/QGIS_DATA_MEUSE/CAPAS/groundwater_SHP.shp', 'Parameter' : 'gw', 'RPLOTS' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }
```

R execution commands

```
options("repos"="https://cran.at.r-project.org/ ")
.libPaths("C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rlibs")
tryCatch(find.package("sf"), error = function(e) install.packages("sf", dependencies=TRUE))
library("sf")
tryCatch(find.package("raster"), error = function(e) install.packages("raster", dependencies=TRUE))
library("raster")
tryCatch(find.package("ggplot2"), error = function(e) install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE))
library("ggplot2")
Layer <- st_read("C:/Users/pedro/Desktop/R_and_Qgis/QGIS_DATA_MEUSE/CAPAS/groundwater_SHP.shp", quiet = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Parameter <- "gw"
RPLOTS <- "C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_NrkcUZ/c1d698df3c114f0ba8683f055e935159/RPLOTS.html"
png("C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_NrkcUZ/54d674612e0544ec9c189b752431c340/RPLOTS.png")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(NULL, aes(Layer[[Parameter]])) + geom_histogram()
dev.off()
```

R execution console output

> Installing package into
> 'C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/processing/rlibs'
> (as 'lib' is unspecified) Warning: unable to access index for
> repository https://cran.at.r-project.org/ /src/contrib: no fue posible
> abrir la URL 'https://cran.at.r-project.org/ /src/contrib/PACKAGES'
> Warning: unable to access index for repository
> https://cran.at.r-project.org/ /bin/windows/contrib/4.2: no fue
> posible abrir la URL 'https://cran.at.r-project.org/
> /bin/windows/contrib/4.2/PACKAGES' Warning message: package 'sf' is
> not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Error in library("sf") : there is no package called 'sf'
EjecuciÃ³n interrumpida
Execution completed in 0.37 segundos
Resultados:
{'RPLOTS': 'C:/Users/pedro/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_NrkcUZ/1aa2aa77d0534b43839fd32793970961/RPLOTS.html'}

Cargando las capas resultantes
Algoritmo '1. Histogram 1' finalizado
La salida HTML ha sido generada por este algoritmo.
Abra el diálogo de resultados para comprobarla.[image]

Comment: Did you set R folder? Checks the steps of [MappingGIS](https://mappinggis.com/2019/09/como-integrar-r-en-qgis-3/)

Answer (score 1):

I have already found the problem. The problem was a simple extra space at the end of the URL of the package repository. The URL was "https://cran.at.r-project.org/ ". I just had to delete it and it worked.
The correct one is without the space: "https://cran.at.r-project.org/"

Note that when I first installed the complement R process, this was the default setting.